Converting a Multi-Tenant Web Application to On-Premise
I have a multi-tenant SaaS application that needs to be converted in a way that makes On-Premise installations of it possible.
I want to ensure that the source code is inaccessible and the application can only be accessed after a license (key or file) has been provided. I attempted to install the application along with all the necessary components on a VM and then convert it into a VMDK, but the maintenance of it is hectic and not valid if you have a bunch of clients that request the On-Premise version.
I also Dockerized the application and its components but as long as the client has Root access to the server, they can easily access the source code.
What are preferred methods to convert an existing Web Application to an On-Premise application. Some additional information that might be helpful:

The application is a SaaS and allows multiple tenants, each on their own subdomain
The On-Premise client should only be able to create/have one organization (one tenant)

